# How to use fetch assoc and fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to know who is logging in to the system so i want to get the position of user logging in and take them to their place of work. i dont know how to use fetch assoc or fetch array thank you in advance for helping me .. hope you understand guys and sorry

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$tableName = "";
$position = "";

function login($tableName)
{
    global $connect, $email, $password;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE email=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement);    
    return ($count == 1);

}

if (login('tbl_users')) {

    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['email'];

    header('Location:../index.html');

} else if (login('tbl_gramusers')) {
    $row['position'];
    echo $row;

    //   header('Location:../stocks_index.html');
    //header('Location:../admin.html');     
} else {
    echo 'Wrong Username or password!';
}
```

Comment: once it reach`return ($count == 1);` below lines will not execute

Comment: thank you but how will get the position column and a specific data there?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions. Also, why are you mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions? Also

Comment: sorry i didn't see, i just copied it from my old work